# Xamarin Forms handle prop de un objeto

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

tengo un objeto mi `.xaml`  como este :

```
 <local:StepProgressBarControl StepColor="#128C7E" Steps="5" StepSelected="1" x:Name="stepBar"/>

           <Label BindingContext="{x:Reference stepBar}"
           Text="{Binding StepSelected, StringFormat='{0}'}"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           FontSize="Large"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           BackgroundColor="White"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           x:Name="lblmain"/>
```

lo que quiero es cachar el valor de su **StepSelected** cuando cambie y a partir de ahi ejecutar un metodo

se que puedo accesar al valor de este objeto con algo asi

```
var x = stepBar.StepSelected;
```

entonces quiero saber como adjuntarle un metodo a este evento si el valor de StepSelected cambia.
Alguien podria ayudarme?

esta es la clase del `local:StepProgressBarControl`

```
 public class StepProgressBarControl : StackLayout
{
    Button _lastStepSelected;
    public static readonly BindableProperty StepsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Steps), typeof(int), typeof(StepProgressBarControl), 0);
    public static readonly BindableProperty StepSelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(StepSelected), typeof(int), typeof(StepProgressBarControl), 0, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public static readonly BindableProperty StepColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(StepColor), typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Color), typeof(StepProgressBarControl), Color.Black, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public Color StepColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(StepColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StepColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Steps
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StepsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StepsProperty, value); }
    }

    public int StepSelected
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StepSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StepSelectedProperty, value); }
    }


    public StepProgressBarControl()
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Padding = new Thickness(10, 0);

        Spacing = 0;
        AddStyles();

    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == StepsProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Steps; i++)
            {
                var button = new Button()
                {
                    Text = $"{i + 1}",
                    ClassId = $"{i + 1}",
                    Style = Resources["unSelectedStyle"] as Style
                };

                button.Clicked += Handle_Clicked;

                this.Children.Add(button);

                if (i < Steps - 1)
                {
                    var separatorLine = new BoxView()
                    {
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Silver,
                        HeightRequest = 1,
                        WidthRequest = 5,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                    };
                    this.Children.Add(separatorLine);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (propertyName == StepSelectedProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            var children = this.Children.First(p => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ClassId) && Convert.ToInt32(p.ClassId) == StepSelected));
            if (children != null) SelectElement(children as Button);

        }
        else if (propertyName == StepColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            AddStyles();
        }
    }
    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectElement(sender as Button);
    }

    void SelectElement(Button elementSelected)
    {

        if (_lastStepSelected != null) _lastStepSelected.Style = Resources["unSelectedStyle"] as Style;

        elementSelected.Style = Resources["selectedStyle"] as Style;

        StepSelected = Convert.ToInt32(elementSelected.Text);
        _lastStepSelected = elementSelected;

    }

    void AddStyles()
    {
        var unselectedStyle = new Style(typeof(Button))
        {
            Setters = {
                new Setter { Property = BackgroundColorProperty,   Value = Color.White },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderColorProperty,   Value = StepColor },
                new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty,   Value = StepColor },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderWidthProperty,   Value = 0.5 },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderRadiusProperty,   Value = 20 },
                new Setter { Property = HeightRequestProperty,   Value = 40 },
                new Setter { Property = WidthRequestProperty,   Value = 40 }
        }
        };

        var selectedStyle = new Style(typeof(Button))
        {
            Setters = {
                new Setter { Property = BackgroundColorProperty, Value = StepColor },
                new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.White },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderColorProperty, Value = StepColor },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderWidthProperty,   Value = 0.5 },
                new Setter { Property = Button.BorderRadiusProperty,   Value = 20 },
                new Setter { Property = HeightRequestProperty,   Value = 40 },
                new Setter { Property = WidthRequestProperty,   Value = 40 },
                new Setter { Property = Button.FontAttributesProperty,   Value = FontAttributes.Bold }
        }
        };

        Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
        Resources.Add("unSelectedStyle", unselectedStyle);
        Resources.Add("selectedStyle", selectedStyle);
    }
}
```

esta clase me devuelve el valor selecionado pero ese valor necesito manejarlo en mi vista, para poder hacer cosas en base al valor del **SPBC**

Comment: Es un custom renderer?

Comment: si es un objeto que toma todo de una clase aparte

Comment: yo le haria un binding a StepSelected

Comment: podrias poner un ejemplo? con  un metodo muy sencillo como un display alert o algo asi ?

Answer (score 1):

En base a tu pregunta editada, edito mi respuesta y podras saber que seleccionar algun boton en este evento.

Te parsee el Text del boton para tener un indice de que boton elegiste y usarlo, para tu siguiente metodo.

```
    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectElement(sender as Button);

        var boton = sender as Button;

        //Ejecutar Metodo siguiente y el Text del boton te dira cual elegiste
        int seleccion = Convert.ToInt32(boton.Text);
    }
```

Comment: La edite porque no se habia mostrado el codido de tu xaml, ya te busco la doc para que la mires y entiendas lo que quiero mostrarte

Comment: mmm pues ya lo lei bien, pero lo que quiero es cuandoSteps cambie, tome su valor al que cambio y ejecute un metodo como ponerlo en un switch y dado a su valor yo haga o deshaga , esto que propones es un clase para ir contando su valor

Comment: voy a reformular la pregunta mejor.

Comment: Claro, pero en esta clase con el binding detectas el cambio en esa propiedad que hiciste, en el metodo OnProperty ejecutar el metodo que tu quieras. El Contar es un ejemplo nada mas. Entendi por Step que era un contador que tu ibas ingresando, pero podrias llamarlo como quieras y olvidarte que es contador y simplemente captura el valor.

Comment: Steps es un valor fijo?  y StepSelected es para mostrar un avance de ingreso de datos?

Comment: steps si es fijo y step step selected te dice que valor esta selecionado, yo necesito ese valor, para hacer por decir ifStepSelected labelstep1.isvisible = true y asi ... para ello necesito poder tener el valor StepSelected  en una variable o tomarlo del label lblmain y cacharlo cada que ese valor cambie

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105897/discussion-between-ramiro-barone-and-e-rawrdriguez-ophanim).